# How do I get valid lastActivityTime and cloudToDeviceMessageCount values for an IoTHub device?

Tags: azure-iot-hub

When I query the device twins for my active devices, either in code (via the C# SDK or in the Device Explorer), lastActivityTime is always "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z" and cloudToDeviceMessageCount is always 0. Valid fields appear to be deviceId, the etags, status, connectionState, and lastUpdated on the properties metadata fields. Is there additional configuration or provisioning I need to do to obtain the additional information?

Answer (score 0):

We can start to see the Device twins get updated only if we have any status updated from any particular devices, Please see the below images for a detailed steps to demonstrate the device twin updated properties. For example if your device is shutdown or disabled as explained in the below images.

**Steps**: VS code the easy way.

1) Go to the Azure portal-->IoT Hub -->Device and 'Disable' its connection
[image]

2) Go to VS code , right click the device and select 'Get Device Info'

[image]

3) You will see the device twin is reported as the status is "Disconnected" and even the 'StatusUpdatedTime and 'LastActivity' are also reported for the first time and will continue to keep reporting if there is an activity on the particular device.

[image]

**Steps**: Device Explorer, the easy way

1) Open the Device Explorer Twin, Messages to Device-->Select your device and send a Message. You can use the VS Code to Get Device info again as showed in the previous step. Here in the below image you can see the "cloudToDeviceMessageCount":1 , keep on sending further messages from Device explorer and check the message count.

[image]

More info can be obtained from [Understand and use device twins in IoT Hub.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-device-twins)

**Step:** Cloud to device messaging: Azure Portal

Please read more info about [Cloud to device Messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-c2d-guidance)

[image]

**Step**: Using [Azure IoT service SDK NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Devices/). [C# Sample App C2D](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-c2d#send-a-cloud-to-device-message)

[image]
**Happy Azure IoT Learning**

Comment: Thanks for the fast and detailed reply. I am actually able to use IoTHub just fine to send messages to my devices (and have been for some time now), and as I mentioned the status and connectionState fields do seem to update to reflect the state of a device at any given time. However, even when the Overview page shows that I have sent over 10,000 messages in a day, none of the active devices have a non-zero cloudToDeviceMessageCount. Does the device have to do something on it's end to update the count, other than registering for (and receiving) messages?

Comment: Regarding 10K messgaes/day, are you sure all of them are C2D? Have you given a try to pull device info on VS code immediately when you send message to device, rather than an app using SDK? I have updated my answer to show info on C2D messages retention settings, hope this helps you, please mark helpful responses as 'Answer' & Upvote so that they are helpful to others as well. Please do visit [Reference - IoT Hub endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-endpoints)

Comment: That link seems to cover device-to-cloud messages and their retention, not cloud-to-device. I am using Device Explorer, not VS code, and currently have 10 devices showing over 7,500 messages today, and only use cloud-to-device messages. All 10 of my devices show 0 messages even though I have been testing multiple devices all day and successfully sending them messages.

Comment: I've confirmed that sending a message from the IoTHub devices page does increment the message count; the issue is that messages send with the C# SDK using the CloudToDeviceMethod class do not increment the count, even though they make it through to the device as evidenced by it's behavior and the data returned from the device.

Comment: Perhaps I was conflating "cloudToDeviceMessage" with "CloudToDeviceMethod" and assumed using the latter would increment the former. If that is not the case, can you confirm?

Comment: Can you confirm the IoT Hub Tier you are using(Basic or Standard)? [Basic and standard tiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-scaling?branch=release-iotbasic#basic-and-standard-tiers)

Comment: S1 - Standard on an internal MS subscription.

Comment: So I have verified with C# app using Azure IoT Service SDK, sent couple of C2D messages and I can see the count updated when I retrieve the 'Device Info'. Is this what you are looking for ? (Please see my updated answer )

Comment: I have used [ServiceClient.SendAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.serviceclient.sendasync?view=azure-dotnet) for C2D.

Comment: Okay it's clear that I was mixing up direct methods with C2D messages. It's confusing, however, that the official C# SDK class is called CloudToDeviceMethod(not DirectMethod) and that the message count on the overview page increments when I make direct method calls, even though I am not sending any C2D messages. Also, "lastActivityTime" seems a misnomer if it is not updated by direct method calls.

Comment: Let us know if you need further help!Please mark helpful responses as 'Asnwer'

Comment: @ToddHeckel-MSFT, Did you find any workaround or solution on this query/